# How to call an API using Python Requests library

Tags: python, api, python-requests

I can't figure out how to call this api correctly using python urllib or requests.

Let me give you the code I have now:

```
import requests
url = "http://api.cortical.io:80/rest/expressions/similar_terms?retina_name=en_associative&start_index=0&max_results=1&sparsity=1.0&get_fingerprint=false"
params = {"positions":[0,6,7,29]}
headers = { "api-key" : key,
            "Content-Type" : "application/json"}
# Make a get request with the parameters.
response = requests.get(url, params=params, headers=headers)

# Print the content of the response
print(response.content)
```

I've even added in the rest of the parameters to the params variable:

```
url = 'http://api.cortical.io:80/rest/expressions/similar_terms?'
params = {
    "retina_name":"en_associative",
    "start_index":0,
    "max_results":1,
    "sparsity":1.0,
    "get_fingerprint":False,
    "positions":[0,6,7,29]}
```

I get this message back:

> An internal server error has been logged @ Sun Apr 01 00:03:02 UTC
>   2018

So I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. You can test out their api here, but even with testing I can't figure it out. If I go out to http://api.cortical.io/, click on the **Expression** tab, click on the **POST /expressions/similar_terms** option then paste {"positions":[0,6,7,29]} in the body textbox and hit the button, it'll give you a valid response, so nothing is wrong with their API.

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. can you help me?

Comment: Have you checked whether it's a issue with Cortical API and not your code?

Comment: yes I've checked because you can go to their website and test their api, I talked about how to do that in 2nd to last paragraph. their api is up.

Comment: I took your url and copied and pasted it in my browser. It's giving me the same internal server error message. Could you please check the url too?

Comment: @troymyname00 well you don't have my api key, but you can go to their webiste http://api.cortical.io/ and try the api there.

Comment: Oh one problem I see now is that this is a get, but it's suppose to be a post. However. changing that didn't fix it.

Comment: It seems like your'e not using urllib.request. You are directly using the request library. Could you check if that is the problem?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is that you're mixing query string parameters and post data in your `params` dictionary.
Instead, you should use the `params` parameter for your query string data, and the `json` parameter (since the content type is json) for your post body data.

When using the `json` parameter, the Content-Type header is set to 'application/json' by default. Also, when the response is json you can use the [`.json()`](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#json-response-content) method to get a dictionary.

An example,

```
import requests

url = 'http://api.cortical.io:80/rest/expressions/similar_terms?'
params = {
    "retina_name":"en_associative",
    "start_index":0,
    "max_results":1,
    "sparsity":1.0,
    "get_fingerprint":False
}
data = {"positions":[0,6,7,29]}
r = requests.post(url, params=params, json=data)

print(r.status_code)
print(r.json())
```

```
200
[{'term': 'headphones', 'df': 8.991197733061748e-05, 'score': 4.0, 'pos_types': ['NOUN'], 'fingerprint': {'positions': []}}]
```

Answer (score 3):

So, I can't speak to why there's a server error in a third-party API, but I followed your suggestion to try using the API UI directly, and noticed you're using a *totally different endpoint* than the one you're trying to call in your code.  In your code you `GET` from `http://api.cortical.io:80/rest/expressions/similar_terms` but in the UI you `POST` to `http://api.cortical.io/rest/expressions/similar_terms/bulk`.  It's apples and oranges.

Calling the endpoint you mention in the UI call works for me, using the following variation on your code, which requires using `requests.post`, and as was also pointed out by t.m. adam, the `json` parameter for the payload, which also needs to be wrapped in a list:

```
import requests
url = "http://api.cortical.io/rest/expressions/similar_terms/bulk?retina_name=en_associative&start_index=0&max_results=1&sparsity=1.0&get_fingerprint=false"
params = [{"positions":[0,6,7,29]}]
headers = { "api-key" : key,
            "Content-Type" : "application/json"}
# Make a get request with the parameters.
response = requests.post(url, json=params, headers=headers)

# Print the content of the response
print(response.content)
```

Gives:

```
b'[[{"term":"headphones","df":8.991197733061748E-5,"score":4.0,"pos_types":["NOUN"],"fingerprint":{"positions":[]}}]]'
```